# How to change the background opacity when clicking on a search input . And I want the input with focus except input total body will be gray

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kVzp.png)

I tried add some css like

```
body:focus-within{
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
  opacity: 0.5;
  /* filter: blur(3px); */
}
.searchbar1:focus-within{
 background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's simple just create a state and when you click on the input field make the state true than on the state changes you can perform multiple actions like changing classes etc.